# Angular 2 ngFor Object array object not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have this data:

**component.ts**:

```
demo = [{
        'ob1': [{'ob1_first':'value11'}, {'ob1_second':'value12'}],
        'ob2': [{'ob2_first':'value21'}, {'ob2_second':'value22'}],
        }]
```

I want show it in view ngFor, but I still get [Object object]

My html:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of demo">
     {{demo[key]}}
</div>
```

My question is:

How to refer to Object array object in ngFor ?

Comment: For print `value11` you need to do `{{ key.ob1[0].ob1_first }}` you should take another `*ngFor` in main loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the ob1 and ob2 keys in there? It would all work fine if you just had and array of arrays of objects

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is not correct. Still solution is as below,

```
 <div *ngFor="let key of demo">
       {{getValue(key) |json}} <br/>
  </div>

 getValue(key){
    console.log(key)
    return Object.values(key);
 }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/QL3pMAgxzVJgwF8ZITfY?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

demo is an array with 1 object.

*ngFor="let key of demo" -> iterates through the object which is only one in your case.

```
{
       'ob1': [{'ob1_first':'value11'}, {'ob1_second':'value12'}],
       'ob2': [{'ob2_first':'value21'}, {'ob2_second':'value22'}],
   }
```

this gets you the first key ->
          demo[key].ob1 
which has
          [{'ob1_first':'value11'}, {'ob1_second':'value12'}] 
as value.

To access this. 
You have to do

```
*ngFor="let innerkey of key.ob1"
```

then you can access value1  with innerkey.ob1_first

Comment: This solution will only work if you know the key names, not suited for generic iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not iterable directly with *ngFor. To iterate objects, you can use a pipe like this one:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }

}
```

Then, you use it like this to iterate the object:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of demo | keys">
    {{demo[item]}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the format given by you . you can print your demo object using following code

```
<div *ngFor="#itemArr of demo">
    <span >{{itemArr |json}}</span>
</div>
```

But if you want to traverse your json data then you may have to correct it as

```
 this.demo =
  [
      [{'ob1_first':'value11'}, {'ob1_second':'value12'}],
      [{'ob2_first':'value21'}, {'ob2_second':'value22'}]
  ]
```

and then render it as

```
                  <div *ngFor="#itemArr of demo">
                        <div *ngFor="#item of itemArr">
                            <span >{{item |json}}</span>
                        </div>
                       <hr>
                    </div>
```

If still the answer dont solve your problem, Could you state your actual JSON object that you want to render.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div *ngFor="let key of demo">
     {{key}}
</div>
```

Everything in the `demo` is represented as `key` that's the reference to each individual object.

But it seems your object is a bit complicated for `*ngFor` to handle. So consider using `Class` for mapping.

> Demo.ts

```
export class Demo {
  ob1_first: string;
  ob1_second: string;
  ob2_first: string;
  ob2_second: string;
}
```

> component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ......
})
export class Component {
  demoArray: Demo[];

  ngOnInit() {
    // If this throw error you may need to replace with `demo: Demo = new Demo; 
    demo: Demo;
    demo.ob1_first = "value11";
    demo.ob1_second = "value12";
    demo.ob2_first = "value21";
    demo.obj2_secon = "value22";

    demo2: Demo;
    demo2.ob1_first = "value11";
    demo2.ob1_second = "value12";
    demo2.ob2_first = "value21";
    demo2.obj2_secon = "value22";
    this.demoArray.push(demo);
    this.demoArray.push(demo2);
  }
}
```

> HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let key of demoArray">
     <div>START</div>
     <div>{{key.ob1_first}}</div>
     <div>{{key.ob1_second}}</div>
     <div>{{key.ob2_first}}</div>
     <div>{{key.ob2_second}}</div>
     <div>END</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i do this i get : [object Object]

Comment: That's because you have Object within Object. So you need nested `*ngFor` loops for that.